# Powershell commands variables return empty in ps1 script

Tags: variables, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to simply get some data into a variable (this s just an example of my issue, much bigger script in the works),

> $var=get-physicaldisk

This works if I type it out in powershell, but if I try to script is with ps1 the variables never get filled.  one method Ive used for other variables because of this was the set-variable, but this cant seem to be used in conjunction with a get command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the $var to show up after the script is complete, use this formatting. BEWARE!-- the variables will continue to exist in that powershell session until it is closed

```
$global:foobar=get-process
```

You can also use `$script:foobar=get-process` to have the variable persist throughout the script (within functions and loops)